# Is there a workaround for keeping the flash on when recording starts? (iOS + Expo/Expo-camera)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

My app needs the flash to stay on when recording a video. I'm using expo to develop and test for react-native on both Android and iOS. Android works as expected, but on iOS, setting the flashMode to 'torch' still turns off the flash when recordAsync is called. I've tried using other modules for the torch/flash function, but none work at the same time as the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect workaround, but I ended up using [expo-image-picker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) for the iPhone portion. I added some more helper text for the user to turn on the flash themselves and expo-image-picker is able to launch a stripped down version of the system camera with some restrictions you can set.